# Draw image using OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I want to draw an image using OpenGL ES for Android 2.0 
I got pixel position of image ..How can I perform

Please reply
Thnx in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can upload image data to texture and draw the texture.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh,
Bt still I have confusion,Can u show me hint how it can be.
I am working with Android Platform.

Thanks Again